# ElementNotVisibleException only on amazon ec2 instance with selenium, firefox and xvfb-run

Tags: firefox, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-webdriver

I have the following problem:
I have a java code using selenium (version: 2.43.0) to parse my login web page (that I cannot change) with firefox driver. 
On my windows machine - I am able to get my element and use sendKeys to fill and later submit my form using the the installed firefox.

I am now interested in moving to ec2. I created an amazon instance 
(`os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_51'`).

In order to run selenium, I installed firefox using [this blog post](http://joekiller.com/2012/06/03/install-firefox-on-amazon-linux-x86_64-compiling-gtk/) with slight modification (installed firefox version: 32.0.3 instead the one in the original script), and I am using xvfb-run to run firefox.

The page seem to load on the machine, and the element I am looking for is found (or at least it seems that way), but when I try `element.sendKeys("testUserName");`

I get the following exception:
`org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`
Other answers suggested to use `Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();`

but that didn't help. I still get the same exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I think I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607021/elementnotvisibleexception-only-in-virtual-display

Answer (score 1):

I would try to wait for the element to become visible before interacting with it, if the wait times out you know the element was never visible.

ie:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(yourByLocator);
```

Comment: That is a good idea :) Indeed it time outs. Since the element I am using should be visible at all times I wonder what may be causing this, if the page was not fully loaded, or I have a mistake in my code (that is not very lightly since the same exact code works on windows) I would expect the find element to crash - before getting to this. I hope this is not happening due to the in memory buffer.. Any ideas on how to solve it?