# ElementNotVisibleException only in virtual display

Tags: python, selenium, xvfb, splinter

I have a script that needs to interact with a webpage via selenium. I need to use some kind of virtual display to keep the browser from showing up.

The script as a whole works great until I introduce Xvfb into the mix. When I do that I get an `ElementNotVisibleException` the first time I actually try to interact with the page.

I've tried using `xvfbwrapper` and `pyvirtualdisplay` with the same effect.

And here is code that doesn't work:

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
vdisplay = Xvfb()
vdisplay.start()
oBrowser = Browser()
oBrowser.visit(sUrl)
oBrowser.find_by_id('some_field')[0].fill(sValue)  #<--ERROR
vdisplay.stop()
```

And here is the code that does work (but displays the browser):

```
oBrowser = Browser()
oBrowser.visit(sUrl)
oBrowser.find_by_id('some_field')[0].fill(sValue) #<--works every time
```

So how can I run my code on a virtual display?

I've tried doing a `time.sleep` before trying to fill the field in but the problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with the page loading slowly. Any ideas?

Comment: er... your tags are wrong: it seems you are using splinter(https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), not selenium python bindings (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html).

Comment: @KirilS. Noted. Splinter does it's magic through selenium so at the root of things is a selenium issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround more than a direct solution:

I replaced this line:

```
oBrowser.find_by_id('some_field')[0].fill(sValue)
```

With this:

```
oBrowser.execute_script("document.getElementById('some_field').value = {}".format(sValue))
```

And it works reliably. I'm still not sure why it didn't just work in the first place though.